# Failing at attempting to send file from React to backend using FileReader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, ecmascript-6, filereader

I am attempting to send a file to the backend from React but it is not working.

This is the input type file component:

```
          <FormFieldFile
            onChange={e => {
              const f = e.target.files[0];
              const fr = new FileReader();
              fr.onload = ev2 => {
                console.log(ev2);
                startupFourthStepFormActionHandler({
                  headerimage: ev2.target.result,
                });
              };

              if (f) fr.readAsDataURL(f);
            }}
          />
```

This is the api call:

```
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}uploadFile`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // already tried without this
      },
      // already tried without JSON.stringify
      body: JSON.stringify({ headerimage }),
    });
```

And this is how I call it:

```
CompanyInfoFilesAPICall(startupFourthStepForm.headerimage)
```

This `startupFourthStepForm.headerimage` contains a very big encoded string like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAHGCAYAAACM8u/eAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP...`.

The error I get

```
POST http://some/path/public/api/uploadFile 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

> "Call to a member function getClientSize() on null"

And that error above is like if the object is going to the backend empty.

Comment: What does your backend expect? Why do you send it as a base64 string instead of sending it directly as a binary file?

Comment: Hi @Kaiido. That's the way the FileReader returns its data, as a base64 string. Can you show me how to do what you mentioned?

Comment: Where did you see you need a FileReader? To send a binary, you can simply do `fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: e.target.files[0]})`. But if your server expects it to be part of a multipart-formdata request, then you'd need to set it to the correct field: `const formdata = new FormData(); formdata.append('expected_field', e.target.files[0]); fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: formdata});` Ps: add the `header: { Authorization: \`Bearer ${userToken}\` }}` in the request too if needed.

Comment: What does `expected_field` means? It's an input id or what? @Kaiido

Comment: It would be the `name` of an `<input type="file">` if you did sent it through the default HTML <form> submit. Your backend is probably waiting for something like `$_FILES["input_name"]` in PHP would. where `"input_name"` is set in HTML <input type="file" name="input_name">